# Regarding the proper ways of implementing the training process in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When reading some `Tensorflow` implementations, it seems to me that there are two ways to implement the training process.

For instance, [in this implementation](https://github.com/wwoo/tf_box_classify/blob/master/tf_convnet_test.py), the training segment is like this.

```
with sess.as_default():
sess.run(init_op)
sess.run(init_local_op)  # we need this only with tensorflow 0.10rc
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

try:
    while not coord.should_stop():
        step += 1
        x, y = sess.run([train_image_batch, train_label_batch])
        train_step.run(feed_dict={keep_prob: 0.75,
                                  x_: x, y_: y})

        if step % TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE == 0:
            x, y = sess.run([valid_image_batch, valid_label_batch])
            result = sess.run([merged, accuracy], feed_dict={keep_prob: 1.0,
                                                             x_: x, y_: y})
            summary_str = result[0]
            acc = result[1]
            writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
            print("Accuracy at step %s: %s" % (step, acc))


except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    x, y = sess.run([valid_image_batch, valid_label_batch])
    result = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={keep_prob: 1.0,
                                             x_: x, y_: y})
    print("Validation accuracy: %s" % result[0])

finally:
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

It seems to me that `coord = tf.train.Coordinator()` and `threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)` are used to control the training process. This is kind of different with the way of implementing the training process included in [cifar10 example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py), which seems to me more straightforward, something like `for step in xrange(FLAGS.max_steps):...`.  My questions is that, are there any differences between these two approaches? And when to use which? Thanks.

Comment: They seem to be using the same approach -- `start_queue_runners` is used in both of your examples, and then they execute main training step in a loop (`train_step.run` is an alias for `sess.run(train_step`)

Comment: CIFAR10 example does not use the coord = tf.train.Coordinator(). It is not clear to me when should use coordinator in the training process. Besides, the first example uses  while not coord.should_stop(): to control the iteration, are there any specific reason to use this approach to control the training iteration?

Comment: `should_stop` becomes true on `coord.request_stop()` which is called on `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` which is thrown when the input queue is exhausted. So if you have a set of examples that you want to go through once, you can use pattern in your example